# IE8 doesn't set value of an input

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8

I some divs with forms inside of them and i do have inputs with same ids but in different divs and forms so do like this:

`$("divEdit form #ParentId").val(12);`

it works on chrome/mozilla but not on IE8 
anybody knows why ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't have multiple elements with the same `id` on the same web page. You'll need to use some other method of identification such as a `class` (or with form controls the same `name`).

Comment: do I need to also set id,name for all my forms (is there such a rule)  ?

Comment: No. You only need to use an ID if you need to identify/find that element for example in a JavaScript/jQuery or a Stylesheet. You need to set the name of a form control if you want its value to be submitted (which however is most of the time).

Answer (score 3):

ID attributes **must** be unique in web pages.  It's part of the specification and you will always run into issues using the same id more than once.

http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2